# Is it a good idea to provide course detail in teaching statement?

Tags: application, coursework, assistant-professor, teaching-statement

I am applying for Assistant Professor position at a technical university which requires teaching and research statements as a part of application.

In my teaching statement, I have suggested two courses which I would like to offer in due course of time. I have significant clarity over the content of the courses. The courses would be general purpose (advanced level) but would  be in accordance with my future research plans. The idea for these courses have emerged from my research experience and based on my learning during PhD.

I am wondering if it is a good idea to give the course content in the teaching statement.

PS: I have also mentioned a few courses in my statement which are currently offered by the University and lies in my expertise. These two courses I am talking about are my proposed ones.

Comment: Are you sure the readers will understand your writings about the courses?

Comment: Yes the readers will surely understand, I am applying in my specialization. Is there a specific reason you asked this question?

Comment: Based on your wording, I am not sure you understand everything that should be in a [teaching statement](https://cft.vanderbilt.edu/guides-sub-pages/teaching-statements/).

Comment: Yes the reason is that sometimes the readers of a teaching statement are not familiar or interested in specific courses.

Comment: @mkennedy:  the suggested courses are components of my teaching statement, I have written a elaborated statement. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a matter of opinion, but I would suggest focusing on more general things overall, though you could say that you have well developed ideas for a course in X and in Y. But I think that the teaching statement needs to focus on your teaching philosophy and expertise, rather than details.

I say this because what you suggest seems to make you too narrowly focused. The chances are that you will need to teach other courses, including elementary courses as part of your job.

If you mention the courses and are prepared to talk more deeply when asked, I think it would be better than to give the detail at the expense of other things.

The exception would be if the position itself is focused on the areas of those courses. But still, don't neglect the general/philosophical  part of the statement.

Comment: Thank you. I have also mentioned a few courses in my statement which are currently offered by the University and lies in my expertise. These two courses I am talking about are my proposed ones.